# C++ Split System.String and use in String.Format

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

Essentially, I have a string that has placeholders that I am passing into String::Format(), as such:

```
"The {0} brown {1} jumped over the {2} {3}."
```

And I have another comma delimited string which contains the strings I wish to fill in to the formatting placeholders, as such:

```
"quick,fox,lazy,dog"
```

So it would only seem natural that to fill the format string I would `Split(',')` the second string, and pass that as the second argument in `Format(first_str, second_split_array)`;

But splitting the second array produces a System::Array^ which Format() sees as only one object, thus getting angry and telling me my index must be less than or equal to the number of arguments passed.

Last I heard, `String.Format()` can use an array as the second arg, so... what do I have to do to get the string split in a way that Format() will see as all the args?

**Edit:**

The idea here is that the number of indexed elements is not the same every time. The goal I am trying to achieve is to take data sent from a server and fill it in to a template. The server sends back a comma delimited list and a template name. So, for the quick fox example it'd send what I have above, but other times It'll send, say, error, which uses:

`"An error has occurred: {0}
(Details: {1})"`

and the server arguments `"Error Name,Error text description and such."`

Comment: But the amount of possible indexed results from the comma delimited list can be anything. I'll edit to elaborate.

Comment: I checked msdn again. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you're passing an `array<String^>^` as the second argument to `String::Format`. If you want the overload of `String::Format` that takes an array as the second argument (and uses each element in the array as the formatting items), you need to pass an **`array<Object^>^`** (where each `Object^` is a `String^`).

Comment: I saw that in the MSDN article, I'm assuming there isn't a direct cast, so... I'd have to create an `Array<Object^>^` and populate it with values from my string array?

Comment: I think so. It not a big change, as a String^ can be converted to an Object^ automatically (no cast). The only thing that will change is the declaration of the Array variable.

Comment: I was originally using `System::Array^ MainArgs = server_response.Split(',');` and changed it to `array<System::Object^>^ MainArgs = server_response.Split(',');` and I think it might be working fine... I'll do more tests.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the question is really about, you can indeed pass an array of strings to String::Format().  The String::Split() method makes it simple to generate one:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    String^ text = "quick,fox,lazy,dog";
    array<String^>^ words = text->Split(',');
    String^ result = String::Format("The {0} brown {1} jumped over the {2} {3}.", words);
    Console::WriteLine(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.